# Laravel 7 Foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, laravel-7

I am doing a Foreign key relationship with two tables.
the parent table:

```
        Schema::create('tests', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigInteger('id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

and the child table

```
        Schema::create('target_sectors', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('sector');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('tests_id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('tests_id')->references('id')->on('tests')->onDelete('cascade');

        });
```

and here are the models for both :

```
use App\TargetSectors;


class Test extends Model
{
    public function TargetSectors(){
        return $this->hasMany(TargetSectors::class);
  
    }
}
```

```
use App\Test;

class TargetSectors extends Model
{
    
    public function Test()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Test::class);
    }
}
```

it is not giving me any error in migration or in inserting the data, but still, the tow tables are not connected together, when I try do find the  target sectors connected with the test id it returns null :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAjUq.png)
and when I try to delete a row from the parent it did not delete connected raws with it from the child?
what can be the problem ??

Comment: Use `$table->id()` instead of `$table->bigInteger('id');`

Comment: i  already did that it didn't solve the problem

Comment: Give local/foreign keys to Relationships `return $this->hasMany(TargetSectors::class, 'id', 'tests_id');` Make same to belongsTo . Details in docs : https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Answer (score 1):

I changed the in config\database.php the engine in  the Mysql configuration to be :
'engine' => 'innodb',

Answer (score 0):

Before MYSQl 5.6 the default storage engine was MYISAM. And foreign key constrains not work in MYISAM storage engine. So database relationship not worked there.
But in InnoDB storage engine foreign key constrains/ database relationship  work.

Just add $table->engine = 'InnoDB'; in you table Schema in all migration file.

So the code will be:

```
Schema::create('tests', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->bigInteger('id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
Schema::create('target_sectors', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->id();
        $table->string('sector');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('tests_id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('tests_id')->references('id')->on('tests')->onDelete('cascade');

    });
```